# Sleep / wait between Jenkins "build steps"(not jobs)

Tags: macos, jenkins

I am creating an automation framework in which I have two partitions say p1 and p2 on Mac machine.
For my automation framework it is required that the automation is always run on clean OS.Partition p1 and p2 have the capability to connect to jenkins as slave on login. The following is the workflow:

1. Jenkins tells p1 to restore p2 with clean 10.9 OS(say).
2. After the restoration is done, jenkins tell p1 to reboot into p2
3. jenkins tells p2 to start the automation.

I am having problem between step 2 and 3. When the Mac machine restarts from p1 to p2, jenkins loses connectivity to the slave and fails the build and does not execute the next build step.

Hence my question:

Is there any way to ask jenkins to wait between build steps 2 and 3 such that it waits till the Mac machine is booted into p2. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

from your question, i understand that your build run on slave takes more time since the connection is lost/interuppted. In this you can increase the response time of the slave (*Go to Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Configure, and uncheck the "Response time" box or increase the response time*).

There could be more ideal solution to handle ssh slaves using groovy scripts(have to explore on this)